# Thymeleaf Spring Validation doesn't display

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-validator

I am trying display error message on HTML which i got from Controller, but i dont see the message displaying.

I printed the ${#fields.hasErrors('name')} and i see it give me false

I debugged my code, and I found there is an error

com.gurnah.controller.ProductController  : product **size must be between 2 and 150**

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/product")
public class ProductController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductController.class);
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepo productRepo;
        .....

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute @Valid Product product, Errors errors, Model model) {

        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("product", new Product());
//          logger.info("Error Message " + bindingResult.getGlobalErrorCount());
            logger.info("Error Message " + errors.getFieldErrorCount());
            List<ObjectError> err = errors.getAllErrors();
            for (ObjectError e : err) {
                logger.info(e.getObjectName()  + e.getDefaultMessage());
            }
//          logger.info("Error Message " + bindingResult.getErrorCount());
            return "/prod/create";
        } else {
            productRepo.save(product);
            return "redirect:/product/list";
        }

    }
```

My Pojo

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ProdID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "product_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="product_generator", sequenceName = "zseq_product", allocationSize=1)
    private int ProdID;

    @NotNull(message = "Field Product cannot be empty")
//  @NotEmpty(message = "Field Product cannot be empty")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 150)
    private String name;

    private String prodDesc;
```

My HTML

```
<form th:object="${product}" th:action="@{/product/save}" method="post">
.....
    <div class="form-group" 
               th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}? 'has-error'">
    <label th:for="name" class="col-form-label">Product Name:</label> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}" />
    <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" 
          th:errors="*{name}" 
          th:class="help-block">Title Errors</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is #fields?

Comment: #fields is built in function or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, yes I was confused :-) But another question: Where does bindingResult comes from?

Comment: I tried first me using BindResult, but it didnot work, so I shifted using Errors, it work the same as Bind Result

Comment: to be clear you can see the error in the log file?

Comment: Yes, i can see the error, as we. Created logger object, you can check my controller,